# Dynamic Template file for subpage

Tags: permalinks, taxonomy

`https://www.example.com/tag_name-tag.php`  is template file for showing posts of any `post_tag`.

`https://www.example.com/tag_name/about`  -  I want to show description of `post_tag` taxonomy term.

how can I do this in WordPress.

#### Edit

I think you did not understood my question.
actually i want to convert this:-

`https://www.example.com/tag-name?content=about`

into

`https://www.example.com/tag-name/about`

Comment: Have you put an actual `tag_name-tag.php` in your root folder? WP already has tag archives, is it that you want to show your own template on the tag archives? Take a look at the template hierarchy, and avoid standalone PHP files that the browser directly accesses like the plague

Comment: i think you did not understood my question.
actually i want to convert this:-

https://www.example.com/tag-name?content=about

into 

https://www.example.com/tag-name/about

Comment: hmmm where does `example.com/tag_name-tag.php` come from? Where does `?content=about` come from? There's no code in your question can you include what you're currently doing in the question so that we might understand?

Comment: actually i want permalink structure like facebook

facebook.com/username/about
facebook.com/username/posts
facebook.com/username/photos
facebook.com/username/videos
facebook.com/username/reviews

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy term should helps you, see the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).

#### The possibilities

- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
- taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
- tag-{slug}.php
- tag-{id}.php

#### Your example

- tag-about.php

See the [template hierarchy for tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#tag) for a deeper documentation about this feature. So it is possible to have a specific template without coding, a plugin.

Comment: i think you did not understood my question.
actually i want to convert this:-

https://www.example.com/tag-name?content=about

into 

https://www.example.com/tag-name/about

Comment: That't true, your edit change the question in deep - so it more a topic for rules to create the url.